# Not able to run JHispter Application. Giving Error : No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: spring, hibernate, jhipster

I am running the JHispter application on Spring tool suite. I had imported the application on my local system. After importing the application i tried running the application using spring boot tools. It is throwing this exception.

`liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:363) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.close(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1176) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:400) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.incyyte.app.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:63) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.incyyte.app.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1235) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1230) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4833) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionProxy.setAutoCommit(ConnectionProxy.java:334) ~[HikariCP-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.HikariConnectionProxy.setAutoCommit(HikariConnectionProxy.java) ~[HikariCP-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:361) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted`

Please let me know what is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error when running from Eclipse.  I dropped all tables from the backend database and then ran `gradlew bootRun` and the blank app started fine.  I could then run the app from Eclipse without issue.